# Authorize Middleware Function

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, express-jwt

I am trying to build the Authorization system in `node.js` and everything works fine with the below code.

**Authorize.js**

```
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const userService = require('../routes/users/user.service');

module.exports = authorize;

function authorize(roles = []) {

    return expressJwt(
      { 
        <<SOME SECRET>>, 
        isRevoked: (req, payload, done) => _isRevoked(req, payload, done, roles) 
      })
      .unless(
      {
        path: [
        ]
      });
}

async function _isRevoked(req, payload, done, roles) {

    var user = await userService.getById(payload.sub);
    var userRoles = payload.role;

    // revoke token if user no longer exists
    if (!user) {
      console.log("Authorization: User not found")
        return done(null, true);
    }

    //check if user is authorized
    if (roles.length && !roles.every(elem => userRoles.indexOf(elem) > -1)) {
                // user's role is not authorized
                return done(null, true);
            }
    done()
};
```

**RoleController.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const authorize = require('helpers/authorize')

router.post('/create', authorize('Admin'), createRole)

module.exports = router

function createRole(req, res, next)
{
    //role creation code goes here
}
```

Everything works fine so far, when the `create` route is requested with the token, `authorize.js` is checking whether the token is valid and after checking if the user role matches with the route role (e.g. `admin` here)

Now, the issue goes here

I am trying to move the `authorize` to middleware in `RoleController.js`. And get the access for the module from `database` based on the requested route through `req.originalUrl`

```
var isAuthorized = function (req, res, next)
{
    authorize(req.originalUrl) // just trying to check the authorization as a first level and moving forward to route only if authorized

    next();
}

router.post('/create', createRole) //Removed authorize here
```

After changing to this, it is not working as desired. The flow goes to the `authorize` function but it is not calling the `_isRevoked` function.

It may be because of `async` in `_isRevoked` but I am stuck here to proceed. Any ideas?

Comment: Inside authorize function i can see isRevoked function defination,where you are calling it??

Comment: It is called automatically with the working code! And, I believe that `expressJwt` will take care of that.

Comment: since `authorize` function returns a function you need to use it like this `authorize(req.originalUrl)(req, res, next)` but it still wouldn't make sence. `authorize` function expects an array of roles so why are you passing in `req.originalUrl` ???

Comment: @Molda, I have removed certain logic for the question to keep it minimal. However, I just realized that I don't need to pass `req.originalUrl` from the calling function as I already have access to `req` in `authorize.js`